# Only show button to loged-in user in Laravel-Collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

How to insert @if statement for only show the "**red color delete action button**" to loged-in user in below code?

[image]

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
  <div class='btn-group'>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

thank you in advenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Auth::check()` like this :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
  <div class='btn-group'>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
    @if (Auth::check())
      {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
    @endif
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Thank you  your answer. By the way, is there have any Auth method like show user login and out activities?

Comment: For now there isn't, all you can do is if the user is authenticated get the current user or the current authenticated user id using this methods `$user = Auth::user(); 
 $id = Auth::id();` and log a user in and more authentication things see [documentation ;)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)

Comment: could you answer to this question link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703535/only-show-button-to-loged-in-user-in-laravel

Comment: @Magnetic let us have a chat about this problem [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156528/problem-solution)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<div class='btn-group'>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
    <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
    @if(Auth::check())
        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
            {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif
</div>
```

Note that I have moved your form inside of the if statement for you here, if you'd still like the other buttons to be wrapped inside a form use the following code

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
    <div class='btn-group'>
            <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
            <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        @if(Auth::check())
             {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
        @endif
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```