# Only show button to loged-in user in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravelcollective

If I logged in as John, how can I show only the red button for John instead of Susan's one?

**Test system environment: Win10, Laravel5.4, Mysql5.7.19.**

[image]

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="jobs-table">
    ...
    @foreach($jobs as $job)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $job->user_name !!}</td>
            ...
            <td>{!! $job->created_at !!}</td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                <div class='btn-group'>
                    <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
                    <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: both john and Susan has different roles?

Comment: @urfusion, there are not using role system yet. thanks.

Comment: Hi what is the difference between the two ??

Comment: @Maraboc, Hi:) this is add a small function to check what logged in user's Job in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you only want to show that button on the rows that belong to that user.

This is a slight assumption, but I assume there is some sort of user identifier on that job row - ideally something like a `user_id` that links the row to the associated user.

If that's the case then you can just use a simple if statement for that button.

Something like the below would work with what you have:

```
@if ($job->user_id == Auth::id())
    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
@endif
```

If you don't use a user identifier and only store the username then something like the below would work - using the user_name (I assume this is unique?):

```
@if ($job->user_name == Auth::user()->user_name)
    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, but In both cases, it works invisibly red button. I also checked with different user login.:(

Comment: So I modified  like "if ($job->user_name == Auth::user()->name)". your idea was correct :). hava a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Use Laravel [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies) feature:

```
@can('delete', $job)
    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
@endcan
```

or:

```
@if (auth()->user()->can('delete', $job))
    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: thanks. but result was (3/3) ErrorException
Undefined variable: $post. How can I use "can" statement in this code?

Comment: @Magnetic you need to create a policy first, please read the docs. Then use `$job` instead of `$post`. `$post` was just an example from docs.

Comment: thank u for your advice. I need to learn about using the Policies feature.:)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Role system will make this more easier so consider adding role system